# Let $H$ be a subgroup of a finite group $G.$ Suppose $(\sigma, W)$ and $(\sigma', W')$ be representation of $H$ over $\mathbb{C}$.

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

Let $H$ be a subgroup of a finite group $G$, and $(\sigma,W)$ and $(\sigma'W')$ be representation of $H$ over $\mathbb{C}$.

Let ${\rm Ind}_H^G \sigma$ be  $${\rm Ind}_H^G \sigma = \{f:G \rightarrow W | f(hg) = σ(h) f(g) \ \  \forall h\in H, g \in G \}$$
Then, if $\sigma$ and $\sigma'$ are isomorphism of representation, why ${\rm Ind}_H^G \sigma$ and ${\rm Ind}_H^G \sigma'$ is isomorphic ?

I want to construct concrete isomorphism between them.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you think of using the intertwining maps? In case that $\sigma$ and $\sigma'$ are isomorphic representations, their intertwining map must be an isomorphism of $W$.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the only reason you are confused is because here $\sigma$ and $\sigma'$ have the same underlying vector space $W$. For clarity, let's have $\phi : W \to W'$ be an isomorphism of the representations $(\sigma, W)$ and $(\sigma', W')$. Then elements of $\operatorname{Ind}^G_H \sigma$ are maps $f : G \to W$, while elements of $\operatorname{Ind}^G_H \sigma'$ are maps $g : G \to W'$. An isomorphism of these induced representations must turn maps of the former kind into maps of the latter kind, so given the data we have available (only $\phi$) how can we do this?

**Spoiler:** The only way I can think of is to map $f \mapsto \phi \circ f$. We need to check that actually $\phi \circ f \in \operatorname{Ind}^G_H \sigma'$, but this is essentially by definition. Then since $\phi$ is invertible, the assignment $f \mapsto \phi \circ f$ is invertible too. It just remains to prove that the assignment $f \mapsto \phi \circ f$ intertwines $\operatorname{Ind}^G_H \sigma$ and $\operatorname{Ind}^G_H \sigma'$, but there isn't really anything to do here either.

Comment: Thank you ! Sorry.. the same underlying vector space was just my typo.. I modified.

Comment: Sorry to ask basic questions because I'm beginner of representation theory, but could you tell me more how to prove $φ・f$ is invertible  using $φ$ is invertible? And in my definition, I didn't assume $f$ to be linear, is $f$ just a map ?

Comment: @Catsoup It doesn't say $\phi\cdot f$ is invertible, it says the map $f\mapsto \phi\circ f$ is invertible.

Comment: (That's right, and the inverse is $g \mapsto \phi^{-1} \circ g$.)

Comment: Where I used the condition that φ is isom ? I think the condition was used only in φ is proving f→φ・f is invertible and the map φ・f is well defined. And the condition is not used in proving intertwined property, is this correct ?

Comment: @mathpencil That's pretty much it: taking induced representations is something called a *functor* (by so-called Frobebius reciprocity adjoint to restriction of representations, if you know what that means), so there is still a map of induced representations when $\phi$ is no invertible. Note that $\phi \circ f$ is still well-defined when $\phi$ is not invertible.